# sql create statement that includes primary key and foreign keys and indexes

Tags: mysql, import, export, create-table, alter-table

I exported a database from phpmyadmin and the sql formatted like this

```
CREATE TABLE 'table_1'(
    'id' INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    'name' TEXT NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE
    'table_1' ADD PRIMARY KEY 'table_1_id_primary'('id');
CREATE TABLE 'table_2'(
    'id' INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    'table_1' INT NOT NULL,
    'name' TEXT NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE
    'table_2' ADD PRIMARY KEY 'table_2_id_primary'('id');
ALTER TABLE
    'table_2' ADD INDEX 'table_2_table_1_index'('table_1');
ALTER TABLE
    'table_2' ADD CONSTRAINT 'table_2_table_1_foreign' FOREIGN KEY('table_1') REFERENCES 'table_1'('id');
```

I want to import this database to [drawsql](https://drawsql.app/). I found out that drawsql can parse `Create` statement only (It ignores `ALTER` statements). So I need to convert this script to include the primary key and the foreign keys (relationships) and the indexes inside the create statement. So the previous script would be

```
CREATE TABLE `table_1`(
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `table_2`(
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `table_1` INT NOT NULL,
    `name` TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (table_1) REFERENCES table_1(id)
);
```

Is there an online tool that can do this transformation?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this using `mysqldump` from a command line. I executed `mysqldump -u <user_name> --no-data --skip-add-drop-table <database_name>`. And then saved the output to a file and imported it to drawsql.